# Bios utility can't read file

Tags: bios

Trying to flash bios for Asus B85M-E motherboard. Bios utility has reported that it can't read file. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please describe the steps you took so far

Answer (score 1):

That's a BIOS file for **B85M-E R2**, not **B85M-E**. [Download the correct BIOS from Asus website](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/B85ME/HelpDesk_Download/).